# Mac OSX : how to close the user's session from my app programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, session, terminal

Is it possible to close the user's session from my OSX app programmatically ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should define the term for those ignorant like me who don't know what 'user's session' is.

Answer (score 0):

```
skill -KILL -u `whoami`
```

This should logout the current user, though there might be better ways of doing this.

Comment: `skill` is not on my PATH. Where is it supposed to be?